# Android: Connecting webview with camera

Tags: android, camera, webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I open camera in webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803914/can-i-open-camera-in-webview)

I'm having difficulty setting up the webview so that there can be javascript callbacks to access the android camera.  Has anyone done this before, or have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yyou can use [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), which provides Javascript hooks into native device functionality (i.e., the camera).

You can view a list of supported features [here](http://www.phonegap.com/features), and read their Camera API documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera).