# File Upload Form via WebView doesn't work with a instant click from camera (Nougat)

Tags: android, webview, upload, camera, android-7.0-nougat

my name is Daniel and I'm learning Android App Dev.

With the code below its possible to attach a file selecting it via file browsing, but what I also need is to call the native android camera app to take a instant photo with the camera and the provide the Upload Form the correct path to the file.

During some testes I could log.v the path to the file, which showed a valid path, since got there and could see the created photo.

I've tried several solutions around the web and couldn't find anything specific for API 25 and above, what seems to be the cause of the problem.

```
package br.com.fahrenheitdlp.ouvidoria;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR = 1;

    private final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        // Chamando o teste de permissões
        checkingForPermissions();

        // Ajustando o WebView
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.requestFocus();
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

        // Carrega a página da ouvidoria
        webView.loadUrl("http://suporte.mesquita.rj.gov.br/ouvidoriaweb/");
//        webView.loadUrl("http://files.fm");

        // Configura o upload de arquivos apartir do armazenamento externo ou câmera
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"Escolha um arquivo"), FCR);
            }
            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FCR);
            }
            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
            }
            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if (mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent();
                takePictureIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider";
                    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, authorities, photoFile);
                    Log.v(TAG, imageUri.toString());
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;


                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "TakePicture não é NULL");
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "TakePicture é NULL");
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }



                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Escolha um arquivo");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP   ) {
            if (requestCode != FCR || mUMA == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null || data.getDataString() == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCM != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }

            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        } else {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = data == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : data.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }

        // ScanFile so it will be appeared on Gallery
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(mCM);
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{imageUri.getPath()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    }
                });
    }

    // Criando um arquivo de imagem
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "OW_"+timeStamp+"_";
        //File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );
        mCM = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }

    // Função para checagem de permissões
    private void checkingForPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            int hasReadExtPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int hasCameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

            if (hasReadExtPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Contacts",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (hasCameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Contacts",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

        } else {
            List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

            final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
                permissionsNeeded.add("Cartão de Memória");
            if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
                permissionsNeeded.add("Câmera");

            if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
                if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
                    // Será necessário usar Rationale
                    String message = "Para anexar arquivos, por favor conceda acesso ao(à): " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
                    for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                        message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
                    showMessageOKCancel(message,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }
    }

    // Função para o agrupamento das permissões que não foram cedidas
    private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Checa o uso do Rationale
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                // Inicializando o HashMap perms
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Preenchendo com os resultados
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                // Determinando as permissões já cedidas
                if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        || perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Alguma das permissões foi negada em algum momento
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alguma permissão foi negada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
            break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    // Cuidado do alerta de permissão
    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Permitir", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Negar", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    // Callback do WebView
    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack()){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="br.gov.rj.mesquita.ouvidoriaweb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Ouvidoria Web"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".App"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup" >

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="Ouvidoria Web"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance for everyone!

Best regards,
Daniel.

Comment: Shit sir, if this is your first question, so well formed and following the rules, you deserve to get your answer. My +1 for the question.

Comment: Please [read this post, maybe it helps!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803914/can-i-open-camera-in-webview)

Comment: Ty sir, but that post compreends and old example. Unfortunately it doesnt work with Nougat. Since API 23 we work with "boolean onShowFileChooser" and not a "void openFileChooser" anymore. In my code you can choose between uploading a file by browsing the storage or by taking a photo. But when we touch the camera icon on file chooser it opens the native Nougat android camera app and lets you take a photo, and I can even see it on my gallery afterwards. I was cabaple of checking that the Uri is passed on as a content (mandatory on Nougat), I just cant understand why the Form isnt catching it.